# React: Checking if an image source / url is empty then return a different url?

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="someClass">
    <img src={this.getImage(item.image_url)}/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to check if the source or image_url is empty then if it is, return a different source or image url?

Thanks

Comment: In javascript: `let x = '' || "Something else"`; then x will be "Something else". This is because the empty string is a [falsey-value](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/). So if it's given that item.image_url defaults to null/undefined/'' when not set -> `this.getImage(item.image_url || "https://mybackup.img/hilarious") ` (although the backup URL might be better pulled into a const or some such).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<div className="someClass">
    <img src={item.image_url !== '' ? this.getImage(item.image_url) : 'different url'}/>
</div>
```

Comment: shorter version `item.image_url ? this.getImage(item.image_url) : 'different url'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an improvement of the previous ans.

```
<div className="someClass">
    <img src={item.image_url !== null ? this.getImage(item.image_url) : 'different url'}/>
</div>
```